# Is not a valid Win32 application error on IIS

Tags: asp.net, iis, hosting, 32bit-64bit, legacy

I have an **Asp.Net Web Api** project that uses a 32 bit dll. I can deploy and use the application on IIS my own machine after changing **Enable 32 bit Applications** property of the application pool to **true**. Here are the properties of my windows and IIS:

[image]

But if I try to publish my project to a demo server using the same settings, I'm getting the following error:

> Could not load file or assembly 'ManagerApi.DLL' or one of its
> dependencies.  is not a valid Win32 application. (Exception from
> HRESULT: 0x800700C1)

Here is the versions of windows and IIS on the demo server:

[image]

How can I overcome this error?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: And application pool on demo server is also set to "Enable 32 bit Applications" ?

Comment: It is either a) not finding the interoped assembly or b) the COM DLL is not registered in the local registry. Simply copying DIB to the /bin folder is not enough when you are monkeying with COM.

Comment: Thanks @OndrejSvejdar. I tried registering the dll by command regsvr32 but I saw a message box saying that "The module x may not compatible with the version of Windows that you're running. Check if the module is compatible with an x86(32 bit) or x64(64 bit) version of regsrv32.exe."